# How to get in Linux application statistics about Ethernet?

Tags: c, linux, ethernet

Is it possible to retrieve various statistics about errors (such as `rx_crc_error`) in C application, similar to those given in `ethtool`? I've searched some time how to do this, but did not find whether it is possible to be done from C application.

Comment: look at the package `bwm-ng` which is a light weight net stat monitor. You may be able to use a pipe to keep an eye on the statistics you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `/proc/`, so read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); perhaps read (sequentially) some file under `/proc/sys/net/` (or, as commented by [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal), `/proc/net/dev`)

Comment: `/proc/net/dev`, to be exact. First two lines are headers, followed by one line per network device. It is always in the C locale (non-localized, in other words). It is part of the Linux kernel userspace API, and as such, unlikely to change.